# Recebendo JSON com PHP via $http.post()

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post, http-headers

Quero **ler** um JSON no PHP recebido de uma função `$http.post()` do AngularJS, já tentei usar `json_decode()` e configurar o header (tanto no PHP como no Angular) mas não funcionou. O PHP acusa ser um índice indefinido, tentei usar o var_dump e ele retorna NULL.

**Angular**

```
$http.post(path, $scope.meuJson, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            ... 
        })
```

**PHP**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = json_decode($_POST['meuJson']);
```

**var_dump($_POST)**

```
array(0) {
}
```

**OBS:** consigo ver os dados sendo enviados como payload da minha requisição pela Network

Comment: de um `var_dump($_POST)` e adicione o resultado à sua pergunta

Comment: Esse retorno não é um jSon

Comment: Eu não sei nada de angular, mas se você passa o *valor* de `$scope.meuJson`, como o framework saberia com que chave isso seria postado? Como sugeriu o @ErlonCharles, edite a pergunta com a saída de `var_dump($_POST)` para esclarecermos isso.

Comment: Poste o formato dos mdados que você quer enviar, não precisa ser exatamente os dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não tem como pegar os dados do angular via $_POST, pois eles não vem serializados como parâmetros no corpo da requisição.

Para obter o corpo da requisição, leia os dados desta forma:

```
$meuPost = file_get_contents("php://input");

$json = json_decode( $meuPost );
```

O `php://input` é uma entrada para o corpo da requisição bruta enviada pelo browser, antes do parse pelo PHP. A grosso modo, seria comparável a ler o `stdin` num aplicativo local (não é a mesma coisa, mas para ilustrar o que acontece).

Comment: Poderia explicar a função do "php://input" faz?

Comment: @YuriJeanFabris dei uma explicação resumida, depois faço uma elaborada, assim que tiver um tempo livre.